# Powershell or Command Line to set wallpaper on windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

Is there a powershell or command line I can use to set the wallpaper on windows 8.1? I tried running the following but no luck? I have 70 tablets and would like to just run a batch file on each to set all the customizations.

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d  wallpaper_path /f
```

It says that the following UpdatePerUserSystemParameters is not found?

```
 RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Comment: Is that your complete code?

Comment: Yes, I tried different variations. And I see the reg key being set then when I reboot it is set back to default

Comment: I resorted to creating a theme and applying the theme from a powershell snippet.  If that is acceptable I will post as answer. FYI, themepack files set 4 things at once, all or none.  Desktop Background, Color, Sounds, Screen Saver will be affected, just in case you have 70 employee's who might complain about favorite screen saver.

Comment: Thank you, sure I would like to see how you accomplished this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why your reg command isn't working, but I know that the following works:

```
set-itemproperty -path "HKCU:Control Panel\Desktop" -name wallpaper -value $image
```

Of note: this sets the property in HKCU (HKEY_CURRENT_USER) and so will affect the user associated with the Powershell session that ran the command. To run this command for another user, I would run it in a Powershell session as that user.